# Novell IDM Apple Open Directory LDAP Driver

Tags: ldap, novell, dscl, netiq

I have been looking for information or examples of how to setup an IDM driver for Apple Open Directory. The articles I have found don't give much detail and pretty much no actual technical content.

I am using the LDAP driver and can connect and create a user on the OD side. However, the issue I am running into is how to set and synchronize passwords. Since it appears that the LDAP driver is not able to set the encrypted password correctly I was going to use dscl to set the password after the user is created by the driver. Since this step must occur after the XDS is submitted on the subscriber channel, can I create a follow-up event to trigger the dscl command or can I use the status message that comes back on the publisher channel?

It seems like synchronizing eDir to Apple Open Directory with IDM should not be something new. I am a little surprised that there is not an existing driver configuration in the Designer palette or at least some more detailed examples or discussions in the forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I worked out was to write custom Java classes to make command line calls to the ODM server to set the password and also to do some group updates.  90% of the work is done using the standard LDAP driver.